# Why does the US want other nations to support them in their sanctions policies?

Tags: united-states, sanctions

I have read a little bit about US sanctions against Russia and Iran.

**Why do they require other countries too to stop/minimise trading with Iran and Russia?**

Certain things that I can remember now:

1. Requiring countries not to buy oil from Iran. Nations might want to buy Iranian or Venezuelan oil also, not just Saudi oil.
2. Requiring countries not to buy Russian weapons like S-400. If I remember it correctly, *US offered India THAAD if India cancels S-400*. Russian weapons are comparatively cheaper than American or Israeli weapons.

Aren't other countries free to buy from whoever they want?

Assuming it's the money that US doesn't want to go to Iran, can nations trade with Iran using *barter system* (give us oil, we shall give you wheat)?

---

Edit: At first, I thought it's based on opinions. No it's not. **"Either with us, or against us"**. There are papers on this. I have to check those whenever possible.

Comment: Dear downvoters, you are free to downvote. I respect that. However, it's the basic social etiquette to tell the reason either in comment (problems with the question) or as an answer.

Comment: My guess would be that the downvotes are because the answer is not that difficult to find. SE is not a discussion board, it is a Q&A board for questions which are *not* on wikipedia.

Comment: @SeverusSnape, not downvoting, but I doubt if emotional answers/comments are welcome here, so maybe that is the reason, why here isn't list of such comments/answers from that four downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious (and simplistic) answer is that sanctions work best if most countries follow them.

So if the US **does** think it worthwhile to enact sanctions, the next step is to build the greatest possible coalition which applies those sanctions. That might require *persuasion* of the partner countries, *negotiation and compromise* on the scope of the sanctions, and possibly political *pressure and coercion* to get reluctant partners to go along.

A powerful country like the US can pressure others by saying, in effect, **"you can trade with us or with them; if you trade with them, *we* won't trade with you."** Other countries then have the choice of going along with the US, or going *against* the US.

- Getting China to stop trade with North Korea was difficult. Chinese sanctions on North Korea became a bargaining chip in other US-China negotiations.
- The EU at first resisted the latest round of Iran sanctions and then mostly gave in. They wanted to keep JCPOA, but they didn't want to break with the Trump administration over that.

Comment: Sort of like the kid in elementary who threatens to take his ball home haha! Good answer by the  way!